# Discriminant of subfield divides discriminant cyclotomic field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Basically I have a question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/377768) answer of a question, but since it is already 10 years old I doubt that anyone will answer me if I write a comment, so I have to write a new question.

The author of this anwser claims that "One property of discriminants is that if $K$ is a subfield of $L$ then the discriminant of $L$ is divisible by the discriminant of $K$ raised to the power of the degree $[L:K]$." Unfortunately I have no idea where this result comes from.

I have currently started studying algebraic number theory by reading the book "Number Fields" from Marcus and I just finished chapter 2, where discriminants were introduced. However, this theorem above is not stated in this book (or I am just blind) neither it is trivial in my opinion. Therefore I would really appreciate if anyone could give me a reference to this theorem or even a proof right here.

Comment: Did you mean cyclo**tomic** field?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:    No, he didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unfortunately I have no idea where this result comes from.

This result, which is definitely not trivial, comes from a study of a more refined object of a number field $F$ than its discriminant ${\rm disc}(F)$, which is called its *different ideal* $D_F$.  While ${\rm disc}(F)$ is in $\mathbf Z$, the different ideal $D_F$ is a nonzero ideal up in $\mathcal O_F$ and the ideal norm of the different ideal is the absolute value of the discriminant: ${\rm N}(D_F) = |{\rm disc}(F)|$.  Multiplicative relations among different ideals become multiplicaive relations among discriminants by taking ideal norms.

It can shown for each number field $K$ contained in a number field $L$ that the extension of $D_K$ to an ideal in $O_L$ is a factor of $D_L$: $$D_L = (D_K\mathcal O_L)\mathfrak a$$ for a certain ideal $\mathfrak a$ in $\mathcal O_L$. (Concretely, $\mathfrak a$ is what's called the *relative different* ideal $D_{L/K}$, so what we have with different ideals is a nice multiplicative tower relation $D_{L/\mathbf Q} = D_{L/K}D_{K/\mathbf Q}$, where $D_{L/\mathbf Q} = D_L$ and $D_{L/\mathbf Q} = D_K$). Taking the ideal norm of both sides of the displayed equation and using transitivity of the ideal norm in towers, which is an ideal-theoretic analogue of the transitivity of the field norm in towers for finite extensions of fields,
$$
|{\rm disc}(L)| = {\rm N}(D_L) = {\rm N}(D_K\mathcal O_L){\rm N}(\mathfrak a) = {\rm N}(D_K)^{[L:K]}{\rm N}(\mathfrak a) = |{\rm disc}(K)|^{[L:K]}{\rm N}(\mathfrak a), 
$$
so $|{\rm disc}(K)|^{[L:K]} \mid |{\rm disc}(L)|$. Dropping the absolute value signs, we get ${\rm disc}(K)^{[L:K]} \mid {\rm disc}(L)$, which is the result you were asking about.

In short, there is a nice multiplicative relation in a tower of number fields between their different ideals, and it turns into a more complicated-looking relation between their discriminants by taking ideal norms.

Comment: I would guess that this can be proved with less machinery by taking an integral basis of $K$ and extending it to a basis of $L$ consisting of algebraic integers.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer that integral basis extension property came up in a question in this site last month to prove discriminant divisibility in an extension of number fields: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4700180/can-an-integral-basis-be-extended